# Terraform create resources seperately for each item in list (Cloudwatch Dashboard: Create row of 3 different metric widgets for each Lambda in list?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-template-file

I am fairly new to Terraform, being much more familiar with Cloudformation, but I am enjoying the ease with which I can create multiple resources from lists of vars.

Any help really appreciated.

TASK:

Create CW dashboard to monitor a list of Lambda functions for **error rate**, **throttle rate** and **duration anomaly**.

I have defined the widget for each of these metrics in TF.

I would like the dashboard to show these three widgets in a row, along with a markdown text section, for each lambda:

Desired outcome:

```
Lambda_Dashboard
  MARKDOWN_TEXT_BLOCK: LAMBDA_1
    LAMBDA_1_error_rate_widget - LAMBDA_1_throttle_rate_widget - LAMBDA_1_duration_anomaly_widget

  MARKDOWN_TEXT_BLOCK: LAMBDA_2
    LAMBDA_2_error_rate_widget - LAMBDA_2_throttle_rate_widget - LAMBDA_2_duration_anomaly_widget

# and so on...
```

I have a list of Lambda functions and each widget defined in TF, example:

```
    error_rate_widget = {
      type   = "metric"
      width  = 8
      height = 6
      y      = 1,
      x      = 0,
      properties = {
         ...
      }
    }
```

PROBLEM:

I have only been able to create blocks of the same widgets for each lambda.

This link (https://github.com/silinternational/terraform-aws-ecs-service-cloudwatch-dashboard/blob/develop/main.tf) shows what I mean:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_dashboard" "main" {
  dashboard_name = var.dashboard_name
  dashboard_body = jsonencode({
    widgets = local.widgets
  })
}

locals {
  widgets = [for service_name in var.service_names : {
    type   = "metric"
    width  = 18
    height = 6
    properties = {
      ...
  }]
}
```

This syntax only results in resources grouped by metric widget (i.e. all the error_rate_widgets for every Lambda grouped together, same for the throttle_rate_widgets, and so on) - and then only for one lambda.

Has anyone done this before or can anyone shed some light on how I could do this please? Code examples would be really helpful due to my inexperience here.

Thank you!

ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:

I thought I might be able to create seperate lists of all the metric widget resources like this, but haven't able to get it to work/am not sure of the syntax (please excuse pseudo code):

```
  error_widgets = [all_lambdas]
  throttle_widgets = [all_lambdas]
  duration_anomaly_widgets = [all_lambdas]
  # IN DASHBOARD RESOURCE : 
  for i in count(lambdas): 
    Text: title {lambdas[i]}
    error_widget[i]
    throttle_widgets[i]
    duration_anomaly_widgets[i]
```

Or maybe some ugly nested for loops (again, pseudocode)?

```
  dashboard_body = {
    widgets = [for lambda_function in var.lambda_functions : [
      for widget in local.widgets : {
        lambda_function = lambda_function
      }
    ]
  ]}
```